# How can i check if the task is running on my User?

Tags: powershell

```
$a = 1
while($a = 1){
    $explorer = Get-Process explorer.exe -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -IncludeUserName
    if ($explorer.Administrator) {
    }

    else{
        start explorer
    }
    
    timeout 10
}
```

I need to get the task from my user... Any ideas.

We are in a project on one computer. My friend is connected with Remotedesktop. We troll each other with closing the explorer etc. I want to restart the explorer after he closed it. His is still running. Thats the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `Get-Process` with `-IncludeUserName`

```
$explorer = Get-Process explorer -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -IncludeUserName
$explorer.UserName
```

But the `IncludeUserName` parameter requires elevated user rights. Run script as Administrator.

UPD. This will help you with process start if there is no explorer running with your username. Replace `put_your_username_here` to your username.

```
while($true){
    $flagToStart = $true
    $explorersArray = Get-Process "explorer" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -IncludeUserName
    foreach($explorerProc in $explorersArray) {
        if ($explorerProc.UserName -like "*put_your_username_here") {
            Write-Output "No need to restart"
            $flagToStart = $false
        }
    }
    if($flagToStart -eq $true) {
        Start-Process -FilePath "explorer"
    }
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
}
```

Comment: Why are using the task Telegram?

Comment: When im am trying this, the explorer is just starting over and over again.... But thank you for the information.

Comment: Telegram is just an example. I tried this with explorer and it works just the same. No restarting. Keep in mind that $explorer.UserName with be with **Computer Name** like `COMP001\User`. You can split it with `$username = $explorer.UserName -split '\\'` and `$username = $username[1]`.

Comment: Do you maybe have an example in a code. I'm not that familiar with powershell scripts.

Comment: See UDP section in my answer.

Comment: Thank you i'll try that. I'm sorry for my late answers. We had some problems with our webserver :) But know i have time to get back to the little script.